# Error operacional de sqlite3

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo una aplicacion para logear. Cuando llamo el metodo logear, este llama a otro metodo(en un modulo aparte) q hace una consulta a la base de datos buscando q el nombre de usuario y la contraseña coincidan, pero cuando toca validar, me lanza un error operacional sobre la contraseña cifrada.

Esta es la funcion q se llama al escoger la opcion de iniciar sesion:

```
def Logear(self):
        usuario_nombre = input("Enigu vian uzantnomon: ")
        clave = input("Skribu vian pasvorton: ")
        usuario = modelo.usuario('','', clave, usuario_nombre)
        login = usuario.identificar()
        if usuario_nombre == login[4] and clave == login[3]:
            print(f"Bonvenon {usuario_nombre}")
        else:
            print("Vi enigis malprave vian uzantnomon aŭ vian pasvorton.")
```

Este es el metodo llamado desde la clase usuario:

```
def identificar(self):
        #Cifrado
        cifrado = hashlib.sha256()#Crea objeto q guarda con cifrado sha256 
        cifrado.update(self.clave.encode('utf8'))#Codifica el argumento luego de convertirlo a bytes
        cifrado = cifrado.hexdigest()
        #Consulta para comprobar si el usuario existe
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE Nombre_Usuario = {self.nombreUsuario} AND Contraseña = {cifrado};"
        cursor.execute(sql)#EXACTAMENTE AQUI ME DICE QUE DA ERROR
        resultado = cursor.fetchone()
        return resultado
```

El error que lanza la consola es: sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "12b0f0dcaefb10c02a83aa9adb025978ddb5512dc04eb39df6811c6a6bf9770c"
Alguien sabe como arreglarlo o al menos q está saliendo mal? Porque las otras funciones trabajan bien.

Answer (score 0):

Uff finalmente di con los problemas.
Primeramente olvide las comillas entre self.nombreUsuario y cifrado.
Luego de arreglar eso no importaba si metia el usuario y la contraseña bien nunca me aceptaba y me enviaba al else q dice #print("Vi enigis malprave vian uzantnomon aŭ vian pasvorton.")#
Entonces me di cuenta que olvidé cifrar la clave dentro de la funcion Logear, asi q me comparaba una contraseña en texto plano con su version cifrada, asi q obviamente nunca iba a coincidir.
xD